# Install Ubuntu 18.04 LTS on small SSD and HDD

Tags: system-installation, mount, 18.04, ssd, partitioning

I read some topics concerning the subject but mostly people have bigger SSD than mine. I have samsung 530U with built-in 14,9GB SSD. I would like to use it somehow but last time I installed Ubuntu on that SSD it ended with lack of space for updates and so on very quickly.

How should I mount Ubuntu so I could take advantage of this SSD and not get into trouble in couple of months with inceasing size of operating system. I must add I use hibernation very often.

Is it possible?

Thank you for all suggestions.

Edit: My computer has 8GB RAM, Intel® Core™ i5-2467M CPU @ 1.60GHz × 4 , Intel® Sandybridge Mobile GPU, 64 bit, 14.9 GB SSD, 500GB HDD

Edit2: I do clean-up very often with BleachBit with root permissions. Nevertheless system is getting bigger with time even I do that so it is not a solution.

Comment: You should add the hard-drive size and how much ram the machine has to your question.

Comment: If you ran out of space because of updates, make sure you delete all downloaded update packages after they are installed. You can safely delete all deb files from `/var/cache/apt/archives`. I think executing `sudo apt clean` or `sudo apt autoclean` deletes these files too. Try also ubuntu-tweak's utility janitor, which uninstalls and cleans files that are not needed any more.

Comment: You may try selecting **Minimal Installation** during installation of Ubuntu. It will install Ubuntu with a few essential tools.

Comment: You want to separate system ( root) from your data by installing /home or a /mnt/data partition on HDD. I have / on SSD and data on HDD, and my old Trusty install used for two years is 13GB, my Xenial uses 8GB, and clean installs of both Bionic & Cosmic are about 5GB leaving lots of room in /. But I do houseclean regularly.

Comment: " I must add I use hibernation very often. "  Why? I have an ssd+hdd setup and always turn my notebook off. Booting takes less than 10 seconds. Yes hibernation is almost instant but booting seems quick enough for me (as I commute I want speedy boot and shutdown times ;) )

Answer (score 0):

According to the space requirements on [this page](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/DiskSpace#Absolute_Requirements), 15 GB is the absolute requirement for Ubuntu:

> The required disk space for an out-of-the-box Ubuntu installation is said to be 15 GB. However, that does not take into account the space needed for a file-system or a swap partition.

If you want to install Ubuntu to another drive that is larger, you can always use the smaller SSD to install software you use on a frequent basis, that would benefit from the faster read and write speeds SSDs have.

Comment: Well yes, that is an idea but still after shut down system will take about 4-5 min. to start up. Nevertheless thank you - if I won't be able to install system I would definately want to put there LibreOffice and some other programs. Can you explain how to do it exactly? How can I make programs to install on certain disk?

Comment: @Vielebny edit your question to include these questions, the comments aren't intended for new questions and answers.

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar setup, but also a larger ssd. Normally the use case then is to install system files on the ssd, home directory on the hdd. However I would say unless you really install only the minimum and do not install anything extra, 15 GB is too small, it will cause many problems unless you are very careful. Ideally, you coudl use something like Apple's fusion drive. From what I found, zfs supports something similar on Linux, but that will be more complicated to set up and I haven't tried it. https://superuser.com/questions/669455/is-there-fusion-drive-style-solution-there-for-linux-and-windows (see the relevant answer)
Another solution that is similar and maybe easier to set up is dm-cache https://www.redhat.com/en/blog/improving-read-performance-dm-cache (both require a reinstall though afaik)

Comment: Nope. Keep /home on the ssd. Put the user directories on the hdd (see `./config/user-dirs.dirs`. /home/ has config files that benefit from the speedy ssd).

Answer (score 0):

Option 1,

Mount the `/usr` directory on the SSD
or one of the sub directories such as `/usr/lib` or `/usr/bin`
For quicker access to the most used programs.

The `/usr` directory contains `/usr/bin`, `/usr/games`,  `/usr/include`, `/usr/lib`, `/usr/local`, `/usr/sbin`,  `/usr/share`, `/usr/src`

All the "User System Resources" are stored here. Such as the binaries, libraries, related documents and header files. User programs like LibreOffice, vlc, firefox, mysql-client, python etc. are stored in this directory.

It's one of the most accessed directories in `/`, also one of the largest.

More info on `/usr` see
[Lnux Filesystem Hierarchy /usr](https://www.tldp.org/LDP/Linux-Filesystem-Hierarchy/html/usr.html)

Option 2,

Use the SSD for the swap partition.
The benefit will be a slightly faster startup from hibernation.

To use swap with hibernation will require at least 1 and half times the ram. For 8 gigs of ram the swap partition will need to be at least 12 gigs.

For more info on `swap` see
[Ubuntu Swap Faq](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SwapFaq)

Comment: I have the option 2 implemented right now. Almost all of SSD size is the swap partition. Indeed it starts form hibernation very well. Maybe I should just leave it like that?

Comment: For me I use option 2, that recovery time from hibernation is a real pain. The caveat is that's a lot writes to the ssd. The benefits of the 1st option is an overall performance in loading programs and less writes to the ssd.

Answer (score 0):

> I have samsung 530U with built-in 14,9GB SSD.

I used to have a system that had a root on a 10Gb partition and /home/ on 5Gb. Where I used `./config/user-dirs.dirs` to point to directories on the HDD for my personal data. It worked very well though you will need to keep an eye on what you install.

It might be worth uninstalling sofware you do not tend to use; if you use gEdit as an editor and never touch Libre Office then just delete it. It is a very large bit of software.

Another method I used was to make a partition for `/opt/` and install some software there. I always like to have the latest browser so I used that to install source versions of Firefox and Chrome and delete the browser from Ubuntu. Same can be done with Libre Office: use the snap download to install in /opt/ and remove the one from Ubuntu. You will have not just the latest version but it will cut down on the amount of data in / so have a double benefit.